# Read integer value from excel file using adoadapter

Tags: c#

I'm reading a excel file using adodapter in c#. I used the following code:

```
 connectionString =string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;",
                                excelFilePath);
 string selectStatement = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", workSheetName);

 using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, connectionString))
 {
       adapter.Fill(dsWorkbook, workSheetName);
 }
```

This code works perfectly if the column in Excel contain characters while, if the column in Excel contain only numbers the value is NULL.

I try to set some parameter in the connection string, for example ISAM: but in this case the code generate exception "Could not find installable ISAM"

I expect to read integer value from Excel column.
Anyone have ideas?

Comment: The issue only occurs when the first column in the worksheet are numbers.  The Jet engine thinks the first column is the row index number and removes the columns.  I don't remember the solution.  Been a very long time since I've seen the issue.

Comment: Your code pretty much works for me. To avoid the installable ISAM error add single quotes around the content of ExtendedProperties. Otherwise, can you give a minimal reproducible example of the spreadsheet data that results in the problem?

Comment: How can i write connection string? Can you post an example please?

Comment: I try to insert single quotes following your tips and it works. Thank you